# JBoss 7.1.3 Final won't allow @Stateless and @ValidateRequest annotations together but will allow either separately

Tags: java, jboss, annotations, resteasy

Let me start by saying that this works in JBoss 7.1.1 Final so I am not sure if 7.1.3 has introduced a bug or has effectively fixed a combination of annotations that shouldn't work together.

If I annotate my RESTful class with either @ValidateRequest or @Stateless then it works. If I add both annotations then I get:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: Only the root method of an overridden method in an inheritance hierarchy may be annotated with parameter constraints, but there are parameter constraints defined at all of the following overridden methods: [MethodMetaData
```

So:

```
@Path("/somepath")
@Stateless
```

works, and

```
@Path("/somepath")
@ValidateRequest
```

works but

```
@Path("/somepath")
@ValidateRequest
@Stateless
```

Blows up with the above error.

I am more interested in if this is a bug or some specification is causing the two annotations to conflict, as far as I can see there should be no reason why these two annotations shouldn't be usable together.

Comment: I am just wondering why you want to declare the Rest Bean as a @Stateless EJB.

Comment: fair question, I wanted access to @Resource 
    private SessionContext context; plus I need transaction management in my rest service

Comment: have you tried outsourcing the transaction functionality into a dedicated EJB and simply injecting that EJB into the REST Bean? What are you trying to do with the SessionContext you can always access that from an EJB Bean.

Comment: Also I am not sure if you actually want the EJB SessionContext or the HTTP Session (managed via CDI), those are two different things.

Comment: more interested in why it doesn't work in 7.1.3 and does in 7.1.1 to be honest, I have managed to work around the issue by not doing the 2 things together

Comment: upps - not sure why I over read that part...